# Why was Hermione a witch?

Tags: harry-potter

Both of Hermione's parents were muggles but she was a witch. I just finished Half blood prince but there is no explanation about this yet. What is the criterion to be born a witch/wizard? Isn't it necessary that at least one of the parents be a wizard too? May be books have elaborated more on this if some one knows, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's explained in the second book I believe. And movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not depended on any criteria, it mainly depends on **gene** A wizard have to born with the magic gene regardless of their parents.

You can see it in the [harry potter wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Status)

> Those born to Muggle families but **who are skilled with and have the
>   magic gene are referred to as Muggle-borns**. A child born with magic to
>   two Muggle parents is considered a Muggle-born.

[Also they're as powerful as so called pure bloods](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle-born)

> Muggle-born is the term given to a witch or wizard who is born to two
>   non-magical parents. Their magical abilities **do not seem to be at all
>   affected by their Muggle parentage**. In fact, many Muggle-borns have
>   been among the most talented witches and wizards of their time, such
>   as Lily Evans and Hermione Granger.

JK Rowling quoted

> Muggle-borns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family
>   tree, in some cases many, many generations back. The gene resurfaces
>   in some unexpected places.

And you can see many point of views and facts in this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-Muggle-borns-end-up-with-magical-ability?redirected_qid=3739680)

> Muggle-borns are descendants to Squibs. You can consider magic being
>   some form of genetic marker that can go dormant and resurface years or
>   centuries later even.

Comment: Squibs being non-magical children born to magical parents.